# How to get instance of object from XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, instance

I have XML file of object.I want to get instance of that object.But i dont have class.I must read XML and create dynamically how to say class. How to do?

Comment: Perhaps you can create a class dynamically but I doubt you would be able to use it easily. Try to write some client code -- give an example of your xml and show some code what you would want to do with it if you could get an instance of that object.

Comment: <Airspace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>0</id> 
  <gmlId>gmlID231361</gmlId> 
  <IsLoaded>false</IsLoaded> 
- <annotation>
- <Note>
  <id>0</id> 
  <IsLoaded>false</IsLoaded> 
  <purpose>REMARK</purpose> 
- <translatedNote>
- <LinguisticNote>
  <id>0</id> 
  <gmlId>gmlID231371</gmlId> 
  <IsLoaded>false</IsLoaded> 
- <note>
  <id>0</id> 
  <IsLoaded>false</IsLoaded> 
  <lang>eng</lang> 
  <value>Lower limit 2500 FT within the lateral limits of OMR 73</value> 
  </note>
  </LinguisticNote>
... it is some of code

Comment: No that is not code, that is the XML. It belongs in the question, not in the comment. Where is the code? If you don't come up with a real question soon this question is going to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx), it can help but you need .NET 4.

Comment: it is good.But there is problem ,i cannot get values.I show with breakpoint there is value  but i cannot get

Comment: Please, specify your problem more.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ConverBinder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It is 'ConvertBinder': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.convertbinder.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to read data from an XML into your class. If so, you can use the following way to read the data from a file.

```
var records = from r in XElement.Load(@"YourFile.xml").Elements("NodeName")
              select r;
```